# How to assert links count on web page through selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have written below code in a separate class to count links on a particular webpage, How to assert this in a test case class:

public static void navigateToLinkInHomePage() throws Exception {

```
        List<WebElement> linksize = Driver.getDriver().findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        int linksCount = linksize.size();
        System.out.println("Total number of links on home page" + linksCount);
        String[] links = new String[linksCount];
        System.out.println("Number of links available");
        for(int i=0;i<linksCount;i++) {
            links[i]=linksize.get(i).getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println(links[i]);
        }



    }
```

above code is written is CommonAssertion class, How can we Assert this with different test class

Answer (score 0):

Change return type to int.
And return size of list.

### Did you have to use static method?

For more specific answer, 
If you want to get the number of links,

```java
// this method returns List of link url.
    public List<String> nameOfLinks(){
List<WebElement> aTagList = Driver.getDriver().findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    List<String> names = new List();
for(WebElement elem : aTagList){
names.add(elem.getAttributes("href"));
return names;
}

public boolean comapreLists(List<String> list1, List<
```

If you want to assert it using testNG

```
/**
int number : your expected link value
*/
@Test
public void homeLinkNumberTest(int number, List<String> expectedNames){
Asserts.assertTrue(nameOfLinks().containsAll(expectedNames);
}
```

This might be works.

Comment: I guess you didn't got my question, I want use this whole method in a assertion, So How can we achieve that?, for eg, I am returning boolean value So I have added a assertion Assert.assertTrue(condition);, what should be the assert condition for this.

Comment: You'd better seperate assertion code from Selenium actions. I wonder if you know about the epected number of links for the test.

Comment: can we assert name of all links using assert